# How do see if a domain is forwarded properly

Tags: php

I am trying to check at the click of a button if a domain name is properly forwarded to a specific URL. How can I do this with PHP? I cannot find any script like this when I did research on this, nor do my developers know how to do this.

Comment: Is gethostbyname() what your looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'll find out. Thanks @shapeshifter

Comment: Yeah, so I answered awhile ago this very question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12282014/1273830).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
dns_get_record
```

Here's [a link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php)!